# Access Admin Panel in SonataAdminBundle without SonataUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata

I work in a Symfony Project with SonataAdminBundle, and I have 3 types of user : **ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN** **ROLE_CORRESPONDANT** and **ROLE_CLIENT**

**ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN** and **ROLE_CORRESPONDANT** have permission to access to Admin Panel,

and in Admin Panel I have a Menu like this :

- Dashbord

  - Products
  - Stocks
  - Operations
- Users

  - Correspondants
  - Clients

But I like to show only this item for **ROLE_CORRESPONDANT**:

- Dashboard

  - Operations
- Users

  - Clients

I now that it is easy with SonataUserBundle, but my problem that I should not use it, I should use only FOSUserBundle,

```
sonata_admin:

    dashboard: 
        groups:
            Accueil:
                icon: '<i class="fa fa-home"></i>'

                items:
                    - app.admin.produit
                    // I would like to define roles her for each item
```

Someone please can help me with idea if it is feasible? 
Thanks for all

Comment: You should not use SonataUserBundle? But you've add it's tag to this question? Please update your question to explain how you build your menu right now. Take a look at KnpMenuBundle if you didn't already.

Comment: I should use SonataAdminBundle, but not use SonataUserBundle

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right. But how do you build your menu right now?

Comment: I build my menu by services

Comment: Services? KnpMenu?

Comment: No, it's with the simple configuration of AdminClass

Comment: @StephanVierkant can you please help me if you have an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

## app/config/config.yml

```
sonata_admin:
    dashboard:
        groups:
            news:
                label:                ~
                label_catalogue:      ~
                items:
                    - sonata.news.admin.post
                    - route:        blog_home
                      label:        Blog
                      roles:        [ ROLE_FOO, ROLE_BAR ]
                    - route:        blog_article
                      route_params: { articleId: 3 }
                      label:        Article
                roles: [ ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN]
```

[link](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/cookbook/recipe_knp_menu.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I don't like to create other route, I like to use route of Sonata,

Comment: This mihgt be the right answer, but it's code only. Please explain your answer.

Comment: I tried test this answer with the default route generated by Sonata for AdminClass, but  I have this error : "Expected either parameters "route" and "label" for array items".